# Looping through selected cells to indent text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I have written the following Google Spreadsheet script that attempts to loop through all selected cells and then update the value so that it adds an indent, by adding `=CONCAT(REPT( CHAR( 160 ), 5),"' + value[row] + '")` around the value.

However I am hitting an error when processing the loop and I am unsure how the code should be modified to correct/resolve. The error I am getting is: `TypeError: Cannot call method "setValue" of undefined.`

Does anyone know what I should change?

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function indentText() {
  var cells = ss.getActiveRange();
  var values = cells.getValues();
  row = [];
  len = [];
  Logger.log(values);

  for (row = 0, len = values.length; row < len; row++) {
    if (values[row] != '') {
      cells[row].setValue('=CONCAT(REPT( CHAR( 160 ), 5),"' + value[row] + '")');
    }
  }

};

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Indent Text",
    functionName : "indentText"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Indent Text", entries);
};
```

---

Edit:  After reviewing my code I now have a working solution.  I have added it here for completeness:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function indentText() {
  var values = ss.getActiveRange().getValues();
  var newValues = new Array();

  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] != '') {
      newValues.push(['=CONCAT(REPT( CHAR( 160 ), 5),"' + values[i][0] + '")']);
    } else {
      newValues.push(['']);  
    }
  }

  ss.getActiveRange().setValues(newValues);

};

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Indent Text",
    functionName : "indentText"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Indent Text", entries);
};
```

Of course would be interested if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Suggest you post things like this here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ... Logs and/or the debugger would track it down.

Comment: Thanks eddyparkinson.  I added this post to codereview but received the following response:

 put on hold as off-topic by syb0rg, Jamal♦ 22 hours ago

This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:....

Comment: ... "Your question must contain working code for us to review it here. For questions regarding specific problems encountered while coding, try Stack Overflow. After getting your code to work, you may edit this question seeking a review of your working code." – syb0rg, Jamal

If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question or leave a comment.

Comment: Sorry, not sure where is the best place. ... Your question is more of a "help me learn how to program" question. So not a good fit for here. Regards the question, one issue is, values is a 2D array https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues() ... I suggest you take the time to understand things.

Comment: hmm... OK.  understand.  I guess I was hoping that the specific issue with my code above might be obvious to someone in the community and they could provide a correction etc.  You are correct though I probably should spend some time to read the reference material provided by Google (if I can find the time :-()

Comment: Ok have taken your advice and hit the Google reference and search sites to find a solution.  For those of you interested here is the final code that after my basic testing appears to work:

Comment: `var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function indentText() {
  var values=ss.getActiveRange().getValues();
  var newValues=new Array();
  for (i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] != '') {
      newValues.push(['=CONCAT(REPT( CHAR( 160 ), 5),"' + values[i][0] + '")']);
    } else {
      newValues.push(['']);  
    }
  }
  ss.getActiveRange().setValues(newValues);
};
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Indent Text",
    functionName : "indentText"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Indent Text", entries);
};`